# Java : Deployment of JAR to Windows exe file

Tags: java, sqlite

I am developing one standalone desktop application using java and sqlite as database, I m using below lines to connect to the database. 
All works fine until distributable JAR file, I mean all functionality (sqlite database read and write operations) works fine in JAR file but problem arising when I am creating .EXE (windows platform) file using Netbeans native packing tool.

After installing .exe in windows, only read operations (sqlite) are functioning  but not write operations to database?

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::resource:database/emp.sqlite");
```

Could someone help me on this?